# cypress clicking on an icon within a table

Tags: html-table, automation, css-selectors, cypress

I am having hard time clicking on an individual icon within this table shown bellow.

I tried the code bellow , but did not work

```js
cy.get('table >tbody >tr td:nth-child(1) fa-icon:nth-child(1)').click({multiple: true})
```

**Visual:**

[image: click on individual icon within a table]

**Inspected DOM:**

[image: click to see inspected elements]

**DOM text:**

```html
<div _ngcontent-ixx-c110 stickything class="d-block grid is-sticky" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; width: auto; left: auto; position: sticky;">
  <div _ngcontent-ixx-c110 class="d-flex ng-star-inserted"> 
    <table _ngcontent-ixx-c110 class="table table-sm table-bordered">
      <thead _ngcontent-ixx-c110 class="bg-color text-center text-black">...</thead>
      <tbody _ngcontent-ixx-c110 class="text-center ng-star-inserted"> 

        <tr _ngcontent-ixx-c110 class="bg-addition ng-star-inserted">
          <td _ngcontent-ixx-c110 class="stickyContainertd ng-star-inserted" style="width: 20px; padding-top: 4px !important;">
            <fa-icon _ngcontent-ixx-c110 size="sm" class="ng-fa-icon ng-star-inserted" css="6">...</fa-icon>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- -->
            Performance insights
          </td>
        </tr>

        ...

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the HTML into the question and not as a photo.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an `:nth-child()` to the row (`<tr>`) as well as column (`<td>`), presuming the rows all have the same pattern of content.

For example:

```js
cy.get('table >tbody >tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) fa-icon:nth-child(1)')
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .click()
```

or `.eq()` works

```js
cy.get('table tbody')
  .find('tr').eq(0)
  .find('td').eq(0)
  .find('fa-icon').eq(0)
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .click()
```